# Targetting nth-child in nested divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a border to the 1st item on the `<div class="about-text-wrap">` however I have tried a combination of every css class I can think of to target the child with nth-child but nothing is working

https://jsfiddle.net/cycf0qsf/3/

```
<div class="block-wrap">
  <div class="grid grid--gutters grid--full gridmd--1of3 gridlg--1of3  gridxl--1of3">
<div class="cell">
  <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/brush.png"/></div>
  <div class="about-text-wrap">
    <div class="about-title">
      <h3>
        Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="about-text">
      <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/flower.png"/></div>
  <div class="about-text-wrap">
    <div class="about-title">
      <h3>
        Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="about-text">
      <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/heart.png"/></div>
  <div class="about-text-wrap">
    <div class="about-title">
      <h3>
        Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="about-text">
      <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 .grid { position:relative; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction:row ;list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 .cell { position:relative; flex:1;flex-direction: column; display:flex; align-items: center; text-align:left;}

.block-wrap{position:absolute; 
top:0;
bottom:330px;
left:0;
right:0;
max-width:1000px; /* Assign a value */
min-height:500px;; /* Assign a value */
margin:auto; background:#fff;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 34px 0px rgba(221,221,221,1); }
 .about-img {padding:20px;}
 .about-text-wrap{height:auto; width:100%; }
 .block-wrap .cell .about-text-wrap:nth-child(1){height:auto; width:100%; border-right:1px solid #e7e7e7;}
 .grid .cell .about-text-wrap:nth-child(1){height:auto; width:100%; border-right:1px solid #e7e7e7;}
 .cell .about-text-wrap:nth-child(1){height:auto; width:100%; border-right:1px solid #e7e7e7;}
 .about-text-wrap:nth-child(1){height:auto; width:100%; border-right:1px solid #e7e7e7;}
.about-title{padding:0 30px;}
.about-text{padding:10px 30px; color:#d0d0d0;}
```

Comment: Do you mean the about-text-wrap, which is in the second cell?

Comment: I updated my answer with your snippet fixed (the bottom position was pushing all up in the fiddle). I think it's what you asked for...

Answer (score 1):

The correct selector would be:

```
.cell:nth-child(2) .about-text-wrap {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

This is saying apply the style to the `about-text-wrap` element located in the 2nd instance(`nth-child(2)`) of `.cell`

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cycf0qsf/2/)

Comment: Thanks,, I've been racking my brains as to why this wasn't working

Comment: You were almost there, the only issue is that you were trying to get the `nth-child` of `.about-text-wrap` when you should have been getting the `nth-child` of `.cell`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that after I posted my answer you changed the element you were trying to target. If you want to target the `.about-text-wrap` element in the first column, you can use `first-child` instead. [Here's a fiddle to show that](https://jsfiddle.net/cycf0qsf/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.about-text-wrap > :nth-child(1) {
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

With `>` you select only the direct children and `:nth-child(1)` selects the first (in this case). If you don't use `>` you are selecting all descendants,any items that are anywhere underneath.

```css
.grid { position:relative; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction:row ;list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.cell { position:relative; flex:1;flex-direction: column; display:flex; align-items: center; text-align:left;}
.about-text-wrap > :nth-child(1) {
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
.block-wrap{position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    max-width:1000px; /* Assign a value */
    min-height:500px;; /* Assign a value */
    margin:auto; background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 34px 0px rgba(221,221,221,1); }
.about-img {padding:20px;}
.about-text-wrap{height:auto; width:100%; }

 
 .about-text-wrap{height:auto; width:100%; }
.about-title{padding:0 30px;}
.about-text{padding:10px 30px; color:#d0d0d0;}
```

```html
<div class="block-wrap">
  <div class="grid grid--gutters grid--full gridmd--1of3 gridlg--1of3 gridxl--1of3">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/brush.png"/></div>
      <div class="about-text-wrap">
        <div class="about-title">
          <h3>
            Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="about-text">
          <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/flower.png"/></div>
      <div class="about-text-wrap">
        <div class="about-title">
          <h3>
            Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="about-text">
          <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="about-img"><img src="../../../assets/img/heart.png"/></div>
      <div class="about-text-wrap">
        <div class="about-title">
          <h3>
            Designed by <br/>10 STRV Designers
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="about-text">
          <h5>Every piece of this car is handmade</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```